# Cube IDE : Error: unknown type name 'HAL_StatusTypeDef'

Tags: stm32, embedded, arm, stm32cubemx, st

I am taking code from a stm32f0 series and trying to convert it to a stm32l4 series dev kit. I have already changed the necessary addresses and include files that I needed to migrate, but I keep on getting the following errors in the stm32l4xx_hal_uart Files:

../Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/stm32l4xx_hal.h:610:1: error: unknown type name 'HAL_StatusTypeDef'; did you mean 'HAL_RTCStateTypeDef'?
 HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_DeInit(void);
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The error appears by this segment of code:

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_HalfDuplex_Init(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart);
```

I have already defined the HAL_UART_MODULE_ENABLED in the stm32l4xx_hal_conf.h and nothing has changed.

What is the cause of this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Find the header file that defines a `HAL_StatusTypeDef` and make sure it gets included. It might help to enable the switch that will have your compiler save the preprocessor output. There really is no magic bullet here.

Comment: I have included it in the header files, that is in the STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver and it still gives me that error, I do not understand by what you mean by enable the switch that will have your compiler save the preprocessor output.

Comment: Do you have a valid stm32l4xx_hal_conf.h file for your project? You're supposed to take stm32l4xx_hal_conf_**template**.h, make a copy named just stm32l4xx_hal_conf.h, and then edit it to enable the particular modules you're using. If you've done that properly then all the STM HAL library includes & typedefs should just work...

Comment: Have you changed the definition of the used controller type in your project settings?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by controller type?

Comment: I find that there was an addressing issue in my flash table that caused the error

Answer (score 16):

I just got the same issue but with an STM32F407 microcontroller. Suddently, the build broke and there were 102 errors saying that HAL_StatusTypeDef was unknown. I followed the path to all the includes, and what I saw is that "stm32f4xx_hal_def.h" includes "stm32f4xx.h", which indirectly re-includes "stm32f4xx_hal_def.h" for each device you have enabled in "stm32f4xx_hal_conf.h". Except that each include of "stm32f4xx_hal_conf.h" includes again "stm32f4xx_hal_def.h", but this will fail, as the #define __STM32F4xx_HAL_DEF guards the file of being included twice !
So the conclusion for me was to always include "stm32f4xx.h", and not any intermediate file, as all these circular includes are calling for trouble !